# How to access nested child nodes of an XML packet

Tags: xml, delphi, soap

I get response from webservice, transform it to datapacket and open in clientdataset1:

```
 ResponseStream:=TStringStream.Create(memo3.Lines.Text,CP_UTF8);
 ResponseStream.CopyFrom(SOAPResponse, 0);
 strXML:=ResponseStream.DataString;
        
XMLTransformProvider1.TransformRead.TransformationFile:=ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)))))+'\WebTransfer\xSave_Waybill.xtr';
ClientDataSet1.close;
ClientDataSet1.XmlData := XMLTransformProvider1.TransformRead.TransformXML(strXML);
dbgrid1.DataSource.DataSet:= Clientdataset1;
ClientDataSet1.Open;
```

ResponseStream.Datastring looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <save_waybillResponse
xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <save_waybillResult>
        <RESULT xmlns="">
          <STATUS>0</STATUS>
          <ID>779940824</ID>
          <GOODS_LIST>
            <GOODS>
              <ERROR>0</ERROR>
              <ID>4518884338</ID>
              <W_NAME>Goods #1</W_NAME>
              <UNIT_ID>1</UNIT_ID>
              <UNIT_TXT> unit</UNIT_TXT>
              <QUANTITY>3</QUANTITY>
              <PRICE>10.596</PRICE>
              <AMOUNT>31.788</AMOUNT>
              <BAR_CODE>032326</BAR_CODE>
              <A_ID>0</A_ID>
              <STATUS>1</STATUS>
              <VAT_TYPE>2</VAT_TYPE>
            </GOODS>
          </GOODS_LIST>
        </RESULT>
      </save_waybillResult>
    </save_waybillResponse>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Datapacket structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

-<DATAPACKET Version="2.0">


-<METADATA>


-<FIELDS>

<FIELD WIDTH="5" fieldtype="string" attrname="STATUS"/>

<FIELD WIDTH="10" fieldtype="string" attrname="ID"/>


-<FIELD fieldtype="nested" attrname="GOODS">


-<FIELDS>

<FIELD WIDTH="1" fieldtype="string" attrname="ERROR"/>

<FIELD WIDTH="10" fieldtype="string" attrname="ID"/>

<FIELD WIDTH="30" fieldtype="string" attrname="W_NAME"/>

<FIELD WIDTH="1" fieldtype="string" attrname="UNIT_ID"/>

<FIELD WIDTH="10" fieldtype="string" attrname="UNIT_TXT"/>

<FIELD WIDTH="10" fieldtype="string" attrname="QUANTITY"/>

<FIELD WIDTH="10" fieldtype="string" attrname="PRICE"/>

<FIELD WIDTH="10" fieldtype="string" attrname="AMOUNT"/>

<FIELD WIDTH="13" fieldtype="string" attrname="BAR_CODE"/>

<FIELD WIDTH="1" fieldtype="string" attrname="A_ID"/>

<FIELD WIDTH="1" fieldtype="string" attrname="STATUS"/>

<FIELD WIDTH="1" fieldtype="string" attrname="VAT_TYPE"/>

</FIELDS>

<PARAMS/>

</FIELD>

</FIELDS>

<PARAMS/>

</METADATA>

<ROWDATA/>

</DATAPACKET>
```

As you can see there are external and internali(placed in nested node `GOODS`) nodes `ID` and  `STATUS`. I can access extra `ID`, `STATUS` nodes but how access internal childnodes `ID` and `STATUS` ?

Included unit module is Xml.xmldom.
Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**
I tried this code. What is wrong in it?  Breakpont on 'ChildNodes.count' shows error `experssion illegal in evaluator`

```
var node1, node2:IxmlNode; 
    nodelist: IXmlNodeList;
for i:=0 to FromServ.save_waybillResult.XMLNode.ChildNodes.Nodes['GOODS_LIST'].ChildNodes.Count-1 do begin
node1:=b.save_waybillResult.XMLNode.ChildNodes.Nodes['GOODS_LIST'].ChildNodes[i];
if node1.NodeName='GOODS' then
 begin
  node2:=node1.childnodes.Nodes['GOODS'];
  if Assigned(node2) then begin
    nodelist:= node2.Childnodes;
    for j:=0 to nodelist.Count do begin
      Showmessage(nodelist.Nodes[j].NodeName);
    end;
   end;
end;
end;
```

this code shows then 3 nodes exists: `ID`, `STATUS`, `GOODS_LIST`:

```
for i:=0 to b.save_waybillResult.XMLNode.ChildNodes.Count do
 begin
 Showmessage(b.save_waybillResult.XMLNode.ChildNodes[i].NodeName);
 end;
showmessage(inttostr(b.save_waybillResult.XMLNode.ChildNodes.Count));
```